# Working with an Intel and Nvidia graphics card on linux mint

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I'm running linux mint 18.1 on a laptop with an onboard Intel graphics card and an Nvidia 970M.

I'd like the desktop environment to use the Intel graphics card, and I would like to use the Nvidia for CUDA libraries (tensorflow, cuda toolkit), and for an occasional game (go kerbal space program!).

I'm familiar with ubuntu-server, but I'm new to the desktop (a windows convert).

Can someone give me a quick rundown of what I need to do to achieve this? Tools? Installations? High level overview of what I need to configure? I need to know what I don't know, I can search for the rest.

I've been at this for a day and a half without success.

Comment: The two graphic cards are coupled via the NVidia Optimus Technology. When you want to use both graphic cards, searching for the Keywords "Bumblebee" and "PRIME" might help you.

Comment: I'm working through these now: http://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/the-state-of-nvidia-optimus-on-linux, 
http://nlug.ml1.co.uk/2016/02/an-almost-authoritative-guide-to-nvidia-prime-and-bumblebee/5065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the ultimate answer is that you need Prime and Bumblebee packages to support Optimus technology (e.g. 2 GPUs).

Prime allows you to switch profiles, meaning you can run the entire system on one or the other GPU (desktop, all apps, etc). Nice click of the button switch (plus a log out).

Bumblebee allows you to preface your programs with `optirun %command%` to run just that process on the NVIDIA GPU.

Know that there are active bugs in this area, I posted a list of resources that got me through all the steps here:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/posting.php?mode=reply&f=59&t=236026